# Match 2 columns of data based on common substring, with a fallback, using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have 2 columns of data: Item numbers and the image name for them (A and C):

Updated sample data:

[image: ![enter image description here]

If an image filename matches the item number, I want to match them in column B (empty) otherwise fall back to a default (if available).

Example: Iterate through column A & C, if image matches the item number, match, otherwise fall back to default. In my case, default would end with either **-5.jpg**, **-4.jpg**, **4-ROOM.jpg** or **5-ROOM.jpg**.

So the desired result (in column B above) would be everything except for **LRL0547A-24.jpg** would be matched with **LRL0547-4-ROOM.jpg** (because it's one of the fallbacks).

My code I've tried is here (I need another pair of eyeballs, mine are hurting):

```
Public Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet, arr(), r As Long, c As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

arr = ws.Range("A2:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)

On Error Resume Next

For r = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For c = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        Select Case True
        Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 9) = "4-ROOM.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 9) = arr(r, 1)
            arr(r, 2) = arr(c, 3)
            Exit For
        Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 6) = "5-ROOM.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 6) = arr(r, 1)
            arr(r, 2) = arr(c, 3)
            Exit For
        Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 6) = "-5.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 6) = arr(r, 1)
            arr(r, 2) = arr(c, 3)
            Exit For
        End Select
    Next
Next

On Error GoTo 0

ws.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem with your posted code?

Comment: I kinda lost track, I think the switch/case statement is not working for the fallbacks. I edited it, my code was slightly different than what i posted originally, sorry, but still not working!? The fallbacks are not being applied when I run it.

Comment: "if image *contains* the item number" - does that mean item number "**ABC-1**" would match image "**ABC-1**2.jpg"  Or do you mean "image name (minus extension) is *same* as item number"

Comment: Just updated the wording, you're right, thank you. The latter case is what I desire.

Comment: Can you visually explain how all the other matches actually matched if the latter in above comment by @TimWilliams is true, especially since you say the only one not matching was the 2nd row?

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop needs to keep checking for an exact match, even if you already found a fallback.

Untested:

```vb
Public Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, arrSku, arrImg, r As Long, c As Long, itm, img, p As Long
    Dim rngSku As Range, rngImg As Range
    Dim exactMatch, fallBack, pm
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set rngSku = ws.Range("A2:B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rngImg = ws.Range("C2:D" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    arrSku = rngSku.Value 'each array has two "columns"
    arrImg = rngImg.Value
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrImg, 1) 'loop the images and remove any extension
        img = Trim(arrImg(r, 1))
        p = InStrRev(img, ".")
        If p > 0 Then img = Left(img, p - 1)
        arrImg(r, 2) = img 'caching the name with no extension back in the array
    Next r
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrSku, 1)
        itm = Trim(arrSku(r, 1))
        exactMatch = "" 'clear any previous matches
        fallBack = ""
        
        For c = 1 To UBound(arrImg, 1)
            img = arrImg(c, 2)            'checking against no-extension value
            If img = itm Then
                exactMatch = arrImg(c, 1) 'with extension
                Exit For 'no need to check further
            Else
                For Each pm In Array("4-ROOM", "5-ROOM", "-5")
                    If itm & pm = img Then
                        fallBack = arrImg(c, 1)
                        Exit For 'stop checking for fallbacks, but keep checking for exact match...
                    End If
                Next pm
            End If
        Next
        'did we make any kind of match?
        If Len(exactMatch) > 0 Then
            arrSku(r, 2) = exactMatch
        ElseIf Len(fallBack) > 0 Then
            arrSku(r, 2) = fallBack
        Else
            arrSku(r, 2) = ""
        End If
    Next
    
    rngSku.Value = arrSku 'put back data into A:B
End Sub
```

If this doesn't do what you want then please post some sample data in text format so I can test.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. However I'm getting an "out of range" error, on the assigning of `img = Trim(arr(c, 3))`. Column A has around 1300 rows and column C (image files) has about 2200. Any ideas on why it's out of range? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry that should have been `img = Trim(arr(r, 3))` Fixed above.

Comment: Thank you, although now same error with this line `arr(r, 4) = img 'caching the name with no extension back in the array`? Looks like the script will work I just am confused on the range errors ..

Comment: Looks like I might need a little re-work on this (posted without testing).  To help out, are you able to share some sample data to save me typing it out?

Comment: Here is the CSV data: https://file.io/7gfI2ViR9BVZ (uploaded on file.io file sharer).

Comment: It runs now, but it's not seeming to make any "fallback" matches.   Can you be more explicit about how those matches should be made.  Your one example is a little fuzzy.

Comment: So it was just supposed to be "If there's an exact match, use that. If no match exists, use either same item number with **-5.jpg**, **-4-ROOM.jpg**, or **8-ROOM.jpg** - does that make sense?

Comment: But your one example is "LRL0547A-24.jpg would be matched with LRL0547-4-ROOM.jpg" which is not super-clear as an example on which to create a "rule" for matching.  You've lopped off the "A-24" from the sku before looking for a match by adding -4-ROOM"   How much should the sku be truncated before trying the "fallback" endings?